# How to host a WCF Service in IIS Programatically?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have a WCF 3.0 service which has been configured in the `web.config` of my web application where it's hosted via an `.svc` file:

```
<endpoint address="https://domain.co.uk/services/accountservice"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
             contract="AccountServiceReference.IAccountService"
             name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
```

The address value shouldn't be in plain text in the web.config, as we'd like to encrypt it with an encryption algorithm that we have and only store the encrypted value there. How would that be possible?

I was thinking perhaps I should be programmatically hosting the WCF service in our IIS so that the address can be set at runtime by reading the `EncryptedAddress` value from an `AppSetting` then decrypting it at runtime. How would that be possible?

Comment: Is this in the `services` or in the `client` section? Because the approach differs quite a bit whether you're trying to host or consume  a service. In either case: why bother? Because this seems like security through obscurity.

Comment: You could try to find out how the .svc file extension works. I believe you will find that WCF implements IHttpHandler. You might be able to rebuild that code-path.

Comment: @codecaster actually I'd need to do this for both client and services.

Answer (score 0):

There are already several answers to your question in stack overflow, for example:

[How to programatically set a single endpoint for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059485/how-to-programatically-set-a-single-endpoint-for-a-wcf-service)

[How can I register a WCF service programmatically within an IIS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522733/how-can-i-register-a-wcf-service-programmatically-within-an-iis-environment)