# How to programmatically change an endpoint's identity configuration?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration, app-config

I am trying to create a tool to modify my service's app.config file programmatically. The code is something like this,

```
string _configurationPath = @"D:\MyService.exe.config";
ExeConfigurationFileMap executionFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
executionFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = _configurationPath;

System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(executionFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModeGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in serviceModeGroup.Client.Endpoints)
{
    if (endpoint.Name == "WSHttpBinding_IMyService")
    {
        endpoint.Address = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
    }
}

config.SaveAs(@"D:\MyService.exe.config");
```

However I have problem changing the endpoint's identity.

I want to have something like:

```
<identity>
     <userPrincipalName value="user@domain.com" />
</identity>
```

for my endpoint configuration, but when i try :

```
endpoint.Identity = new IdentityElement(){
    UserPrincipalName = UserPrincipalNameElement() { Value = "user@domain.com" }
}
```

It fails because the property [endpoint.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.channelendpointelement.identity.aspx) and [identityElement.UserPrincipalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.identityelement.userprincipalname.aspx) is readonly (I'm not sure why, because entity.Address is not read-only)

Is there any way to get around this restriction and set the identity configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this built into the framework, at least I haven't seen anything easy but could be wrong.

I did see an answer to a different question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068075/81251, that uses standard XML manipulation to change the endpoint address. It is a hack, but it would probably do what you want.

Below is the code from the linked answer, for the sake of completeness:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Glenlough.Generations.SupervisorII
{
    public class ConfigSettings
    {

        private static string NodePath = "//system.serviceModel//client//endpoint";
        private ConfigSettings() { }

        public static string GetEndpointAddress()
        {
            return ConfigSettings.loadConfigDocument().SelectSingleNode(NodePath).Attributes["address"].Value;
        }

        public static void SaveEndpointAddress(string endpointAddress)
        {
            // load config document for current assembly
            XmlDocument doc = loadConfigDocument();

            // retrieve appSettings node
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(NodePath);

            if (node == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Error. Could not find endpoint node in config file.");

            try
            {
                // select the 'add' element that contains the key
                //XmlElement elem = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//add[@key='{0}']", key));
                node.Attributes["address"].Value = endpointAddress;

                doc.Save(getConfigFilePath());
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public static XmlDocument loadConfigDocument()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(getConfigFilePath());
                return doc;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new Exception("No configuration file found.", e);
            }
        }

        private static string getConfigFilePath()
        {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is confirmed as working.  What a pain ...

```
public static void ChangeClientEnpoint(string name, Uri newAddress)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModeGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
        ChannelEndpointElement existingElement = null;
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in serviceModeGroup.Client.Endpoints)
        {
            if (endpoint.Name == "BasicHttpBinding_IMembershipService")
            {
                existingElement = endpoint;
            }
        }
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(newAddress.ToString());
        var newElement = new ChannelEndpointElement(endpointAddress, existingElement.Contract)
        {
            BehaviorConfiguration = existingElement.BehaviorConfiguration,
            Binding = existingElement.Binding,
            BindingConfiguration = existingElement.BindingConfiguration,
            Name = existingElement.Name
            // Set other values
        };
        serviceModeGroup.Client.Endpoints.Remove(existingElement);
        serviceModeGroup.Client.Endpoints.Add(newElement);
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/client");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a solution to this, I believe you can achieve it with the following (this is a small extension of the previous example):

```
    public void ChangeMyEndpointConfig(ChannelEndpointElement existingElement, ServiceModelSectionGroup grp, string identityValue)
    {
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(existingElement.Address, EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(identityValue));

        var newElement = new ChannelEndpointElement(endpointAddress, existingElement.Contract)
        {
            BehaviorConfiguration = existingElement.BehaviorConfiguration,
            Binding = existingElement.Binding,
            BindingConfiguration = existingElement.BindingConfiguration,
            Name = existingElement.Name
            // Set other values
        };
        grp.Client.Endpoints.Remove(existingElement);
        grp.Client.Endpoints.Add(newElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx

```
    ServiceEndpoint ep = myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(ICalculator),
                new WSHttpBinding(),
                String.Empty);
EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8088/calc"),
     EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("contoso.com"));
ep.Address = myEndpointAdd;
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to modify and save the config file, not trying to modify a ServiceEndpoint object