# Do WCF Callbacks TimeOut

Tags: .net, wcf, callback, publish-subscribe

I've written a system that uses a Duplex NetTcp Channel with a callback to function as a publish/subscribe server.

Do I have to worry about the callback timing out if not connection is sent after a while or will the callback pipe be maintained indefinitely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The callback won't be maintained indefinitely, It will look for the timeout values you've set in your config. If you enable reliable sessions then you can set the inactivity timeouts of your clients. You can configure timeouts like this:

```
 <netTcpBinding>
    <binding 
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false" 
           ......>
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

When these values are reached and there is still no response, your communication channel becomes faulted and you need to re-create a client proxy to consume the service. The default value for `receiveTimeout` is 10 minutes so you can increase that, but also make sure to increase your `inactivityTimeout` as well, your `inactivityTimeout` should be greater than your `receiveTimeout`.

**EDIT:**

You could keep changing your `receiveTimeout` programmatically based on values your client sends back to the server, the key is keeping the *new* timeout values same on the service and client. 
You would go about doing this on the client (an example I'm taking from a chat service I'm making with WCF and consuming with Silverlight clients):

```
//Create different clients dynamically
MyChatServiceClient _client1 = new MyChatServiceClient( "NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_1");
MyChatServiceClient _client2 = new MyChatServiceClient( "NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_2");
```

In the client configuration:

```
<!--In your config file, define multiple endpoints/behaviors with different values based on your needs-->
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_1" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" ...>
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="283647" maxBufferSize="283647" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_2" receiveTimeout="00:22:00" ...>
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.1.51:4520/VideoChatServer/"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_1"
                contract="IMyChatService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_1" />

          <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.1.51:4522/VideoChatServer/"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_2"
                contract="IMyChatService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyChatService_2" />
        </client>
```

So you can define multiple endpoints or bindings in the config on your client or your server, then based on whatever 
event in your application you can instantiate _clientProxyX to consume _serviceInstanceX which will have different binding/endpoint values 
but the same contract as your *previous* service instance. In the example above the first binding has a timeout of 1 minute, 
the second binding 2 minutes. An important point to consider is that if you wish to recreate new client proxies like this, then you need to tear down your old client
 proxy and crate a new one, which effectively disconnects your clients from the service, at least momentarily.

Also you can modify those values (`openTimeout`, `closeTimeout` etc.) programmatically on both the server when instantiating a new service host.
You can create a new host, based on one of the binding configurations you've defined in your config,
 or create a new config programmatically, something like this:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyChatService));
            var webHttpBinding = new System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding();
            //Modify new timeout values before starting the host
            webHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
            webHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(webHttpBinding, "http://192.168.1.51/myService.svc");
            //start the host after necessary adjustments
            host.Open();
```

This looks quite messy I know, but the point is WCF gives you a lot of flexibility in being able to modify you binding configs programmatically. 
Be sure to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/966349/189756) great answer on modifying your WCF config files. And you can also easily create a whole [service configuration programmtically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292810/189756).

Comment: I want to handle periodic events, would it be acceptable practice to have a "Keep-Alive" message come from the server every x minutes and set the time out to 2*x?

Comment: So you want to keep changing the receiveTimeout based on what your client returns to the server right? I've not done it before but I don't think its necessarily bad practice. Why don't you just set the timeouts to "infinite"? You could also do that programmatically like this: binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(300,0,0,0,0); this will make your receiveTimeout 300 days.