# WCF callback timeout reached?

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

Does WCF callback has a timeout value? Although I set the "receiveTimeout" of "netTcpBinding" to 24 hour , I still get timeout exception therefore it suspect it has something to do with callback time out default value.

```
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding" receiveTimeout="24:0:0" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" maxBufferSize="999999999" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="0:5:30"/>       
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Stack trace

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262256</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-01T14:43:55.8533502Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{5686b79b-3de9-4a6a-981b-ede96ae4da49}" /><Execution ProcessName="MyServiceHosting" ProcessID="1680" ThreadID="13" /><Channel /><Computer>SERVER</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpConnectionResetError.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'. The local IP address and port is 192.167.1.200:8080. The remote IP address and port is 192.167.1.200:49190.</Description><AppDomain>MyServiceHosting.exe</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"></ExtendedData><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ConvertTransferException(SocketException socketException, TimeSpan timeout, Exception originalException, TransferOperation transferOperation, Boolean aborted, String timeoutErrorString, TransferOperation timeoutErrorTransferOperation, SocketConnection socketConnection, TimeSpan remainingTime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ConvertReceiveException(SocketException socketException, TimeSpan remainingTime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EnsureInputClosed(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableListenerOverSession`5.HandleReceiveComplete(TItem item, TInnerChannel channel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableListenerOverSession`5.OnReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

I have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586466/do-wcf-callbacks-timeout) but I don't understand how "inactivity" timeout related to callback timeout ? But callback I mean the callback as in publisher/subscribe and not the method which has  `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]` . My question is what value do I have to set to configure the timeout value of callback?

Comment: The exception may be come from another source on server side(despite it shows timeout exception), which for wcf, the best way is using wcf log, it will show exactly what problem is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry it should be this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @nhabuiduc , I had add the tracing like this

      <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true" />
      <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\WCFLog\logclient.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>