# how to save dynamic endpoints in server app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I create dynamic endpoint like this way on server side:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PokerService.PlayerService));
 for(int i = 1; i <= ; i++)
 {
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(PokerService.IPlayerService), 
                                  new NetTcpBinding(),
                                  @"net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/"+i);
 }
 host.Open();
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068075/622391) to a very similar question

Comment: ok, but i want to add new endpoint in app.config through programatically.

Comment: `XmlDocument` also has [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter.aspx) methods - you can use the same approach to add your own nodes to the config file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your mean here for dynamic endpoint but you can host the service endpoint in app.confog by using the below code in app.config. This app.config must be in that project which is the main project.

```
<system.serviceModel>     
        <services>
          <service name="PokerService.PlayerService">
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="PokerService.IPlayerService" >
    </endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: dynamic means i want to create endpoint like this way:" net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/1 " to  "net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/5".

Comment: The OP wants to add new items to the config file from within the program itself - "dynamic" modification of the config file.

Comment: Configuration Manager is used to modify the app.config file. You can use this to update or read the config file