# WCF client in development mode and when publishing to users with different IP addresses

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

The client application has an app.config file where the IP address of the service is specified <endpoint address= "net. tcp://127.0.0.1:8123/Service". During development, I use 127.0.0.1 to update server references (during which the necessary classes are automatically generated).I have a few servers with wcf services for different group users. Servers have different id addresses. During click-once publishing, I have to specify the IP of and publish my application to each group. How can I configure application to be taken the ip endpoint from app.config when developing, and the ip endpoint from a saved file for user?

Comment: Use a preprocessor Directive : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/

Comment: preprocessor Directive worked when app is run. Add/refresh Service Reference dont use project code, it use svcutil.exe called from studio.

Comment: Set the default option to use deploy option then override during testing to use 127.0.0.1.

Comment: use the "add transform" option on your app.config to create a specific configuration file for each solution configuration.

Comment: Perhaps you can modify the configuration file programmatically to achieve your goal. For this link, you can refer to How to modify the configuration file programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966323/how-to-programmatically-modify-wcf-app-config-endpoint-address-setting

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to change the Endpointaddress for the client every time it connects.

```
string remoteIp="168.0.0.1"; // read from settings
string AuthEndPoint=string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Auth",remoteIp)
srAuth.AuthorizeClient client = new srAuth.AuthorizeClient();
client.Endpoint.Address= new EndpointAddress(AuthEndPoint);
```

And then there are options - either declare a global variable, or ovverride the constructor